# Don't copy package name while copying complete a class code (Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C) code in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, package

Is there any way I can configure Intellij to *NOT* copy the package name at the top of the code when I select and copy it? I need my code to be reusable because I often submit these to an Online Judge and find it tedious (and often forget) to remove this package name everytime.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way it to add a few keyboard shortcuts before you copy:

```
CTRL+HOME         #Go to line 1
DOWN-ARROW        #Go to line 2
CTRL+SHIFT+END    #Select text from cursor to end of file
CTRL+C            #Copy selected text
```

Another set of shortcuts that will accomplish this:

```
CTRL+END          #Go to last line
CTRL+SHIFT+HOME   #Go to line 1
SHIFT+DOWN-ARROW  #Deselect line 1
CTRL+C            #Copy selection
```

There is no native way to configure IntelliJ to ignore a line when copying text.